# Webpack cannot resolve dynamic imports at runtime

Tags: webpack, nrwl-nx

I am using Nx. I built an app using Webpack. Now in a dependent library, there's a dynamic import statement. Webpack gives error on runtime as Module not found with complete path of the file that is not found. Interestingly the file is present in it's location. Basically I am finding all the files that ends with `.migration.js` using glob pattern and then importing them at runtime.

The error stack is:

```
/home/mwaqar666/code/sca/dist/apps/sca-cmd/libs_backend_db_src_index_ts.js:22
                        var e = new Error("Cannot find module '" + req + "'");
                                ^
Error: Cannot find module '/home/mwaqar666/code/sca/dist/libs/backend/data-access-layer/src/domains/user/2022_12_14_09_45_17_941_create-users-table.migration.js'
    at /home/mwaqar666/code/sca/dist/apps/sca-cmd/libs_backend_db_src_index_ts.js:22:12 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
Node.js v18.12.1
Error: Command failed: NODE_ENV=dev node dist/apps/sca-cmd/main.js migration:up
    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:871:11)
    at execSync (node:child_process:943:15)
    at createSyncProcess (/home/mwaqar666/code/sca/node_modules/nx/src/executors/run-commands/run-commands.impl.js:166:34)
    at /home/mwaqar666/code/sca/node_modules/nx/src/executors/run-commands/run-commands.impl.js:113:13
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /home/mwaqar666/code/sca/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:118:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__awaiter (/home/mwaqar666/code/sca/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:114:16)
    at runSerially (/home/mwaqar666/code/sca/node_modules/nx/src/executors/run-commands/run-commands.impl.js:111:20) {
  status: 1,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 52699,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}
```

The file that is reported to be missing is present at it's place in `dist` folder which makes this error even weirder.

**Steps to reproduce this:**

1. Clone this project repo: https://github.com/mwaqar666/sca
2. Switch to branch `backend/backend-integration`.
3. Run `npx nx run sca-cmd:build` (Build the command-line application using Webpack)
4. Run `npx nx run backend-data-access-layer:build` (Build the lib using `tsc` which contains files to import)
5. Run `npx nx run sca-cmd:run:dev --verbose -- migration:up` (This simply executes the `sca-cmd` app using `node`)

**Relevant Info**

```
Webpack version: 5.75.0
Node.js version: 18.12.1
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Nx version: 15.3.3
Typescript version: 4.9.4
```

Comment: did you find a solution for this error? I am trying to solve a similar one